# Handling negative cycles in graphs

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory

We all know that none of Bellman-Ford and Floyd-Warshall algorithms can't handle negative weight cycles, but detect them only. Is there any graph algorithm which could, or would still give correct result in presence of negative cycles?

Comment: If there are negative cycles, then the optimal path is cycling and cycling, so there is not really a correct (finite) solution then.

Comment: What would you want to get as a result? Cost of shortest non-intersecting path?

Answer (score 0):

The network simplex method may do what you want, though it's notably more complicated. https://www.cs.upc.edu/~erodri/webpage/cps/theory/lp/network/slides.pdf

Methods exist for eliminating negative cost cycles though I can't think of their names at the moment.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this? I did a quick look at the slides, which seems like they talk about a variation on the minimum-cost flow problem. The constraints on minimum-cost flows are different than those for shortest paths, in that min-cost flows are well-defined for graphs with negative-weight cycles but shortest paths aren’t necessarily defined for those cases. (Shortest simple paths in a graph can be found, but doing so is NP-hard and presumed to be something we can’t do efficiently.)

Answer (score 0):

There is no algorithm that can find the shortest path in a graph that contains a (reachable) negative cycle, because there *is* no shortest path: you can loop around in the cycle an unlimited number of times, each time making your path shorter (more negative).

You could modify the problem to say that you want the shortest *nonintersecting* path. This problem *is* solvable, but it is NP-hard, so all currently known solutions run in exponential time or worse. That is because any instance of this problem can be transformed to an instance of the [longest path problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem) by negating all the edge weights, and that problem is known to be NP-hard.